# Screen goes off after some time with ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, screen

I am facing the issue after when I switched my DELL Optiplex 330 desktop machine from windows to ubuntu 16.04LTS. I removed GNOME and tried with xface also but no use, screen suddenly goes off while working but CPU will be on as normal.

Comment: You should use lighter variants like Lubuntu or Xubuntu. That hardware is too old for anything more demanding.

Comment: "Xface" indicates gaju tried to do it, @MichaelBay. Maybe a parallel install, instead #ubuntu-desktop. It's not XFCE, gaju?

Comment: @Redbob It's confusing at best. First "Ubuntu" suggests standard Ubuntu, of course. Then "removed GNOME" begs the question, where does Gnome comes from? Lastly "xface" (yes, probably XFCE)... All of this suggests too much "experiments" and if going from a standard Ubuntu the problem is the same whether or not other DEs are installed. Ubuntu+XFCE is not the same as Xubuntu (and even the current Xubuntu may well be too much for an old Intel G31).